# Array not sent by jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send an array using the jQuery ajax function, but it isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
  if (section_name == "first_details_div") {
    var fields_arr = ["f_name", "l_name", "identity_number", "kupat_holim_id", "kupat_holim_insurance_ID", "birth_date", "father_name", "family_status_id"];
    var section_values = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < fields_arr.length; i++) {

      if (document.getElementById(fields_arr[i]))
        section_values[fields_arr[i]] = document.getElementById(fields_arr[i]).value;

    }
  }

  var array_to_send = $.serialize(section_values);

  $.post("ajax_save_intek_section.php", {
      section_name: section_name,
      section_values: array_to_send
    },
    function(data) {
      alert('here!');
      if (data) {
        alert(data); //"<?=getstring('saved_successfully')?>"
      }

    });
```

I tried to add this line before (as I saw in other answer):

```
var array_to_send = $.serialize(section_values);
```

but it doesn't recognize this function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `var array_to_send= $(section_values).serialize();` stead.
but you also can create an object and serialize it with JSON.sttringify(object);

```
  var request = {
     section_name: section_name,
     section_values: section_values
   };

   $.post("ajax_save_intek_section.php", JSON.stringify(request),
     function(data){
       //rest of your code here
     }
   });
```

Comment: I use it `var array_to_send= $(section_values).serialize();` and now it dont throw error, but still not received the array in php page. do try the json?

Comment: well, the description of the function is "Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission." in this case you have to serialize the inputs or the whole form but not a javascript object, in this case use JSON.stringify.

Comment: How are you trying to get the array? Can you see the array in developer console or you may be trying to get the value in incorrect way.

    http://jsbin.com/gefuduxane/edit?html,js,output

Sample for array via ajax. Only thing to note is you will need to get the value in server something like 
  request.getParameter("test[]")

Answer (score 0):

```
//Array of STRINGS
var fields_arr = ["f_name", "l_name", "identity_number", "kupat_holim_id", 

//Array that takes INTEGER as an index
var section_values = new Array();
        for (i = 0; i < fields_arr.length; i++) {        
          if (document.getElementById(fields_arr[i]))

            //giving the STRING as an INDEX to the array instead of INTEGER
            section_values[fields_arr[i]] = document.getElementById(fields_arr[i]).value;        
        }
  }
```

you are doing something like

```
section_values["f_name"]=document.getElementById(fields_arr[i]).value;
```

which will keep your section_values as an empty array. 
I think you wanted to do this instead

```
section_values[i]=document.getElementById(fields_arr[i]).value;
```